# Question about firebase listener and pricing

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Im currently developing a app in react native and Im quite happy with using firebase as the backend solution. However I would have a question regarding the pricing or better said the functionality of listeners. Let us take as an example this function here:

```
const fetchReputation = () => {
        firebase.database().
        ref(`users/${userId}/reputation`).
        on('value', (snapshot) => {
            setReputation(snapshot.val());
        })
    };
```

This is a function which attaches a listener to a specific firebase database value and which gets fired everytime the value changes. I have 2 questions regarding this listener:

1. Is this listener or all kind of listeners always listed as "cloud
   firestore - reads" when I check upon my usage and billing or is this
   listener considered beeing part of the "realtime database -
   downloads" slot? [image]
2. When I leave the screen and come back to the
   screen, the function will get called again, attaching the same
   listener again probably. Do I **always** need to detach a listener
   when I leave a screen and if I need to do that, how do I do it,
   especialy in this particular case? Do I need to call the same
   listener again but with an `.off()` command directly after that?
   How should I do it so the listener keeps working when I am on the
   screen but stops working if I leave the screen 100%?

Comment: Regarding the first question: you are using `firebase.database()...` (i.e. _Realtime Database_), so your usage and billing will be part of "Downloads" slot in _Realtime Database_. _Cloud Firestore_ listeners would look like `firebase.firestore()...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are using the Firebase Realtime Database (FRD) and for that you are charged for the `storage` and `download` and not for the `reads` count.

It is recommended to unlisten when you leave your component that needs the data by calling `.off()` on the `reference` you listened to. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#off).

I personlay like to use `persistent` listeners where I can decide if I want to persist the realtime listener for RTD or Firestore in some cases. For example in a warehouse App we need the list of items very often and almost in every UI part so we start listening on them at some point where we need it the first time and leave the listener open untill the app is closed.

This depends on your usecase. You can make first the solution to `unsubscribe` the listeners and later on adjust the behaviour if needed to fit your needs more.